# javascript get/post cross domain restrictions and facebook/google+ like boxes

Tags: jquery, facebook-like, cross-domain, jquery-get

as far as i know there are cross domain restictions that wont allow you to get content from an external url and in order to overcome this , we use server side scripts.

Im wondering how facebook/google overcomes these restrictions and with a javascript code manage to generate their like box with a simple code like this :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=254277301328504";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

the reason im asking that is because im building a virtual chat bot and want the users to just use a simple javascript to generate the bot in their site(on external domain without them having to use a serverside scripting)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as far as i know there are cross domain restictions that wont allow you to get content from an external url

Not via a “normal” XMLHttpRequest. But that does not mean that external resources can’t be loaded at all. JSONP would be one example of how it can work.

> Im wondering how facebook/google overcomes these restrictions

They create an iframe element inside of your page, and load a document from their own domain into it. And so they have no problem whatsoever communicating with their own domain from the page inside that iframe – because that communication is **not** cross-domain at all.

Comment: so what you are saying is that the call to //connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js generates the iframe ?

Comment: well i have done that and it works :-) but now im facing another problem ... im calling to a javscript generated by php and i want to know the original HTTP_HOST - how can i do that ?

Comment: What HTTP_HOST – what is “original”?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] say that we have 1.php that have the script above ... the script generates an iframe with 2.php as src. now in 2.php i want to get the HTTP_HOST of 1.php ... sorry for the mess

Comment: And 1.php and 2.php are from different domains? Well, then just append that value as a GET parameter to the address of the iframe, then 2.php can read it from there.

Comment: i don't want users (hackers) to know it is an essential value for getting the iframe content, is there another way ?

Comment: Can’t really see a security risk there (if there is one, then you should think hard about your application design … and where you went wrong with it) … but of course you could encrypt the value with a secret that’s only known server-side, if that’ll make you feel better …

Comment: yeah that's a good idea , i have several security measures , the content is delicate so i want to be as safe as possible) and you can never be too safe  :-)